# Adding action helper path in Zend Framework 1.11 for namespaced (5.3) classes

Tags: php, zend-framework, config, ini

Does anyone know how to tell Zend Framework 1.11 how to find my namespaced action helper classes? I'm using proper PHP5.3 Namespaces so not the normal My_Helper etc.

I would love to do this without using an ini file also as I'm not using Zend_Application and don't really want to refactor all my set up.

I can register the view helper path fine with an ini file but cant get action helpers to work.

### Working view helper ini config:

resources.view.helperPath.Foo\View\Helper\ = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Foo/View/Helper/"

### Non-working action helper ini config:

resources.frontController.actionhelperpaths.Foo\Helper\ = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Foo/Helper/"

Cant seem to find any information about it?

If you know how to do it without using Ini files that would be awesome too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, although [ZF1 autoloader can handle genuine PHP namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513529/using-php-namespaces-in-a-zend-framework-v1-application), neither the plugin loader used for view helpers nor the standard resource autoloader (typically used for models, forms, etc) can deal with genuine PHP-5.3 namespace path/prefix mappings ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409424/zend-resource-autoloaders-not-working-for-namespaces)).

It is probably necessary to:

- write your own plugin loader and feed it to the view during bootstrap
- write your own resource autoloader and invoke it in application/model bootstraps.

Bummer. Hope I am wrong.

ZF2 - still in late beta as the time of this writing - is fully capable to dealing with true PHP namespaces.

Comment: It looks like you may be right. I was hoping there was some existing solution but I guess I'll have to try and create my own custom loaders. As for ZF2, it's still not stable and keeps changing a lot so not venturing there for a while. Thanks for the info and linked resources, not sure how I didn't find those.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still sitting on the sidelines of ZF2 for now - watching closely, for sure, but waiting for RC so it's less of a moving target. If you do end up writing a plugin loader and a resource autoloader that are PHP-namespace-capable, I imagine it would certainly be a help to the community to release it as FOSS on github or submit as a patch to ZF1 itself. Hint, hint. ;-) Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Yeah I would certainly be willing to share it if I get it working. Just it's for a personal project so it could be a while before it surfaces :)